# HTML5 Javascript Audio working locally but not on server

Tags: javascript, html, audio

In my project I use audio and Javascript, thus:

I load an array with audio files:

```
var audio = new Array();
for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    audio[i] = new Audio('sounds/sound_' + i + audioExt);
    audio[i].load();
}
```

I then call the audio (on the start event of the drag), as follows:

```
audio[i].play();
```

It works in all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE9, IE8) locally, running Apache from Wamp2.2, but it won't run on any browser once i upload it to the server on GoDaddy (sounds should be made when you drag the animals on the background farm):

http://www.totalliberty.com/cet/farm/

any ideas?

Comment: The audio plays correctly at your example link.

Comment: I hate this uncertainty; I should have chosen a safe profession, like coal mining, or deep water drilling...
Still doesn't work for me on any browser, where on the local it works on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths to the audio files are probably wrong. Now they are relative to the script path which i assume is located under `js/foo.js`, `scripts/foo.js` or something similar. So, either find out the actual path or do some trial and error beginning with `new Audio('../sounds/sound_' + i + audioExt);`.

Comment: First of all... thanks. I really appreciate the time people who do not know me put into trying to help. I will try and reciprocate.
I tried playing with the path, from ***../sounds***  to the absolute  ***/cet/farm/sounds***  but got nowhere. Besides, once the Javascript code is brought from the JS file, shouldn't the paths be relative to the HTML file?

Comment: Yeah, sorry you are right about the paths. Line 43 in parameters.js reads `var audioExt = '.ogg';` but there seems no ogg files exist, only mp3. When changing that line to `var audioExt = '.mp3';` in chrome debugger all audio loads correctly for me.

Comment: I don't get it... I am looking at the sounds directory right now, and it has .ogg, .wav, and .mp3 for all audio files...

Comment: The links doesn't work for me, example: http://www.totalliberty.com/cet/farm/sounds/sound_1.ogg .wav works though.

Comment: ok, mystery No. 2, but the wav file is there, and Firefox should be able to play .wav files, and yet... nada. I did replace the Chrome to do mp3's and it does work, so thanks for that, but IE9 doesn't even load the scene. I think I'm going to throw myself into an open elevator shaft onto some bullets... Why can't we all just live together in harmony?...